# Какие есть программы для в NTFS изменения физических адресов у файлов, для обхода SSD секторов с лагами?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

1. SSD Goldenfir 2TB, спустя 5 месяцев, лагает каждые 15-30 минут на 7 секунд, и каждые 6-е сутки BSOD (видно у Windows счётчик лагов сработал BSOD вызывать).
2. SMART всё ок.
3. Сканирование ФС/HDTune секторов: не видет повреждённых секторов.
4. Нужно поменять адреса файлам которые постоянно пишутся, все файлы реестра Windows, директории кеша браузеров.
5. Программа должно использовать API дефрагментации, и переместить все фрагменты в адреса другие.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что у SSD в принципе существуют "сектора с лагами"?

Comment: Файлы, который часто пишутся, и так периодически переезжают в другие секторы. Это называется wear leveling. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling

Comment: Ни один производитель не заявляет об наличии Wear Leveling (выравнивание износа), даже KingSton. GoldenFir вообще наверно не делали выравнивание износа.

Comment: Абсолютно все SSD делают Wear Leveling, без этого они деградировали бы до уровня флешек